# Why are convex metric spaces defined this way?

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-analysis

If my understanding is correct, a metric space $(X, d)$ is called convex if for all $x \in X$, and $y \in X - \{x\}$ there exists some $z \in X -\{x,y\}$ such that: $$d(x,z) + d(y,z) = d(x,y)$$

I can partially understand the reasoning for defining a convex metric space in this way. However, this definition often seems to give counterintuitive results when $X$ is not a complete space.

For example let $X = \{(x,y): 2 < |x| + |y| < 4 \}$, and $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$, then $(X,d)$ would be convex according to this definition. As $X$ has a hole in its center it clearly fails the [Euclidean test for convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set), so why would we want to define $(X,d)$ as a convex metric space?

Also, it seems to me that we could get closer to the Euclidean definition if we require that for all $x \in X$, $y \in X - \{x\}$, and $w \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $w < d(x,y)$ there is some $z \in X$ such that: $d(x,z) + d(y,z) = d(x,y)$ and $d(x,z) = w$. Why is this definition not used?

Comment: Oops, that was supposed to be the standard distance formula, I will fix that.

Comment: Why is $X$ a convex metric space?  I can't seem to be able to find a point $z$ if $x$ is very close to $(-2,0)$ and $y$ is very close to $(2,0)$.

Comment: I have a general formula which should work, but it is fairly complicated so I felt it would distract from the rest of the post. Let $a_{\alpha \beta} = min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-|3 - |\alpha_1| - |\alpha_2||}{d((\alpha_1,\alpha_2),(\beta_1,\beta_2))+1}\}$, and let $z_{xy}= ((1-a)x_1 + a y_1,(1-a)x_2+ay_2)$.  Then if there are no errors, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $y\in \mathbb{R}$, the statements $z \in X$ and $d(x,z_{xy}) + d(y,z_{xy}) = d(x,y)$ should hold.

Comment: To avoid trivialities, you want to require $z \in X - \{x,y\}$.

Comment: If I haven't made any errors in the above then $z \in X - \{x,y\}$ should always be true unless $x = y$.

Comment: $z=x$ and $z=y$ always satisfy $d(x,z) + d(y,z) = d(x,y)$.

Comment: Can you give an example where $z=x$ or $z=y$ when $x \neq y$? I do not believe such a case is possible.

Comment: What do you mean?  Take any $x$ and $y$ with $x \ne y$, and take $z = x$.

Comment: I misinterpreted which instance of $z$ you were referring to, I thought you meant the $z$ in the formula I presented in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^n$ with Euclidean metric, or more generally in a strictly convex Banach space, a closed subset is a convex metric space  if and only if it is a convex set.

You are right that for non-closed subsets the definition is somewhat strange.  For example, if $C$ is a convex subset of a normed linear space $V$ and $K$ any closed subset of $V$, then $C - K$ (with the metric $d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$) is a convex metric space.